# Docker container cannot share data with host

Tags: selenium, docker

I am running an automated test on a docker container that downloads a file as part of the test. The file ends up in the home/seluser/Download folder of the docker container. But I want to be ale to access it locally on my mac os x.

However, when I run the following command:

```
docker run -v /Users/MyUsername/Downloads/MappedFolder:/home/seluser/Downloads -d -P -p 4444:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome:3.7.1-beryllium
```

The downloaded files don't appear in either the docker container or the host.

As soon as I remove

```
-v /Users/MyUsername/Downloads/MappedFolder:/home/seluser/Downloads
```

and end up with

```
docker run -d -P -p 4444:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome:3.7.1-beryllium
```

the downloaded file shows up in the docker container

I can't seem to find a way to share that data with my host, so I can access the downloaded file in /Users/MyUsername/Downloads/MappedFolder

Answer (score 0):

you are mounting /Users/MyUsername/Downloads/MappedFolder into docker container. 
  so it will overwrite the inside volume of docker container, so you can't see any files in the /home/seluser/Downloads directory, you can able to see data exst in host directory. 
 after running docker container.. you can able see all files whichever you download into  /home/seluser/Downloads or in host directory

Comment: Hi Ashok. Thanks for the reply. Could you kindly demonstrate what you mean, perhaps using a command, similar to the one I have in the original post, of how you think I should share the data between the docker container and the host?

Comment: you are using right command to mount host directory into container  



For example if you mount /data directory into container /opt directory .. then  /data directory will overwrite the /opt directory at docker run time so you can't see any data that exist /opt directory .... Once the container is running and if any data written to /opt directory , you can able to see the same data in /data or /opt  both  inside or outside ,you can access

Comment: That's what I thought. But it not working for some reason. I can't see the downloaded files in the docker container or the host.

Comment: Did you download files after running container..?   and please check permissions of directory

Comment: Yes. The files were downloaded after starting up on the container with docker run......If it was a permissions issue wouldn't there be an error message to reflect that? Is there something I can add to the command to make sure all permissions are as they should be?

Comment: I added sudo at the start of the ‘docker run…’ command in my original post and all the files in the mapped folder on my host where also available in the docker. However, I was unable to run a test because the docker could not be found. Perhaps its because I started it using ‘sudo’?

Comment: This is how I connect with the docker from my java code and this normally works well when I don’t start the docker with ‘sudo’  
return new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://docker:[port]/wd/hub"),
        DesiredCapabilities.chrome())


So I tried adding the docker group using

Docker exec [containerId] sudo groupadd docker

Which seemed fine. However, when I tried adding myself using:

sudo docker exec [containerId] sudo usermod -aG docker [myUsername]
 
I got this:

usermod: user '[myUsername]' does not exist

any ideas?

Comment: I’ve noticed that the reason I am not able to talk to the docker container after starting it up using sudo is likely due to the use of the following command:

export DOCKER_HOST=docker